# Bulma Steps Extension doesn't "step"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

I wrote the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Mockup TOPdesk</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-steps@2.2.1/dist/js/bulma-steps.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-steps@2.2.1/dist/css/bulma-steps.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar is-white">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
               <a class="navbar-item brand-text" href="/">
               TOPdesk Admin
               </a>
               <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenu">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navMenu" class="navbar-menu">
               <div class="navbar-start">
                  <a class="navbar-item" href="admin.html">
                  Home
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-2">
               <aside class="menu">
                  <p class="menu-label">
                     General
                  </p>
                  <ul class="menu-list">
                     <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <p class="menu-label">
                     Actions
                  </p>
                  <ul class="menu-list">
                     <li><a href="compare.html">Compare</a></li>
                     <li><a class="is-active" href="changes.html">Changes</a></li>
                     <li><a href="upload.html">Upload</a></li>
                     <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </aside>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-10">
               <section class="hero is-info welcome is-small">
                  <div class="hero-body">
                     <div class="container">
                        <h1 class="title">View hardware changes</h1>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </section>
               <div class="columns margin-top-15">
                  <div class="column is-12">
                     <div class="steps" id="stepsDemo">
                        <div class="step-item is-active is-success">
                           <div class="step-marker">1</div>
                           <div class="step-details">
                              <p class="step-title">Account</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-item">
                           <div class="step-marker">2</div>
                           <div class="step-details">
                              <p class="step-title">Profile</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-item">
                           <div class="step-marker">3</div>
                           <div class="step-details">
                              <p class="step-title">Social</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-item">
                           <div class="step-marker">4</div>
                           <div class="step-details">
                              <p class="step-title">Finish</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="steps-content">
                           <div class="step-content has-text-centered is-active">
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Username</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control">
                                          <input class="input" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Password</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
                                          <input class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Confirm password</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
                                          <input class="input" type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password" data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Firstname</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control">
                                          <input class="input" name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname" autofocus data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Last name</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
                                          <input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name" data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Email</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
                                          <input class="input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Facebook account</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control">
                                          <input class="input" name="facebook" id="facebook" type="text" placeholder="Facebook account url" autofocus data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field is-horizontal">
                                 <div class="field-label is-normal">
                                    <label class="label">Twitter account</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="field-body">
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <div class="control">
                                          <input class="input" name="twitter" id="twitter" type="text" placeholder="Twitter account url" autofocus data-validate="require">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
                              <h1 class="title is-4">Your account is now created!</h1>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="steps-actions">
                           <div class="steps-action">
                              <a href="#" data-nav="previous" class="button is-light">Previous</a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="steps-action">
                              <a href="#" data-nav="next" class="button is-light">Next</a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But I can't figure out how to use the `Steps` feature from `Bulma`. I have no errors in the console and still the next and previous buttons won't work. I tried putting the JS file on the bottom of the file but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to attach the `Steps` component like this:

```
bulmaSteps.attach();
```

Looks like they forgot to mention it [in the docs](https://wikiki.github.io/components/steps/) for the `Steps` component. They included this for other components like the [`Accordeon`](https://wikiki.github.io/components/accordion/#javascript).

Here is a small working example:

```js
bulmaSteps.attach();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-steps@2.2.1/dist/css/bulma-steps.min.css">

<div class="steps" id="stepsDemo">
  <div class="step-item is-active is-success">
    <div class="step-marker">1</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Account</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">2</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Profile</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">3</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Social</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">4</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Finish</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-content">
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered is-active">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Confirm password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Firstname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname" autofocus data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Last name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Facebook account</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="facebook" id="facebook" type="text" placeholder="Facebook account url" autofocus data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Twitter account</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="twitter" id="twitter" type="text" placeholder="Twitter account url" autofocus data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title is-4">Your account is now created!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-actions">
    <div class="steps-action">
      <a href="#" data-nav="previous" class="button is-light">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="steps-action">
      <a href="#" data-nav="next" class="button is-light">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-steps@2.2.1/dist/js/bulma-steps.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't figure out where I should put that attach method. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Simply put it in script tags after the corresponding markup similar to this: `<script>bulmaSteps.attach();</script>`

Comment: Even if I do that, adding that tag after all the HTML code (copied from your answer), clicking on next takes me to my app home page.

Comment: Ok in that case you have another issue. Do you have a live example online?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/30159/
The weird issue is that in the fiddle it works as intended. I do have steps in a child component, so the href="#" takes me to the default route of my Angular APP.. Also, if I remove the href property, from the buttons, the fiddle still works but in my app, while it doesn't re-route, it does nothing to the steps.

Comment: Ok, will be hard to help you without your whole angular code and a reproduction of your issue. Maby just aks a new question for this!

Comment: is there any way to required field validate?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You could simply use the HTML `required` attribute